# Image Upload using Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, rest, android-studio, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

I am trying to upload an image to the Webserver using retrofit.

The API has been developed using Dot Net.
The API is working fine on postman but shows error in android.

```
URL: https://m13tp89pn9.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/user/UploadImag/userid=67

Authorization = Bearer token
```

This is my interface

```
@Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")
@Multipart
@POST("user/UploadImage")
Call<GeneralPOJO> uploadProfileImage(@Query ("userid") int uid,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Header("Authorization")String header);
```

This is my Code

```
    final String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                    if (path != null) {
                        File file = new File(path);

   RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getAbsolutePath(), mFile);
                        RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());


new RestCaller(ProfileActivity.this, MainApplication.getRestClient().getApiServices().
                                    uploadProfileImage(AppSession.getInt(Constants.LOGIN_UDID), fileToUpload, AppSession.get(Constants.LOGIN_TOKEN)), Constants.REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_PICTURE);
```

Please help me in uploading the image to the server successfully. Please correct my code and tell me what change is required. Thanks

Comment: so whats the error?

Comment: Make sure you are trying add bearer token to request on postman. If that still doesn't work then there's an issue with the endpoint

Comment: 404 https://m13tp89pn9.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/api/user/UploadImage/%7Buserid%7D?userid=67 (2995ms)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Interface

@Multipart
@POST("user/UploadImage/{userid}")
Call<GeneralPOJO> uploadProfileImage(@Path ("userid") int uid,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Header("Authorization")String header);
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide explanation why this is the preferred solution as we want to educate, not just serve ready made code.